# Qual o erro nesse INNER JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, sql-update

Estou tentando fazer um update pegando a contagem de uma coluna de outra tabela com o mesmo cnpj + 1. Fiz todos os testes com os códigos inseridos dentro do contexto e todos funcionaram perfeitamente, mas quando vou fazer o update ele aparece o erro:

> #1064 - Você tem um erro de sintaxe no seu SQL próximo a 'INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(n.numero) AS qtd_notas, n.prestador_cpfcnpj AS cnpjP...' na linha 3.

Não sei mais o que fazer, já tentei INNER, LEFT e é sempre o mesmo erro.

```
UPDATE cadastro c
SET c.ultimanota = (grup.qtd_notas + 1)
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(n.numero) AS qtd_notas, n.prestador_cpfcnpj AS cnpjPrest 
     FROM notas AS n 
     WHERE n.prestador_cpfcnpj 
     IN ( SELECT c.cnpj FROM cadastro AS c) 
     GROUP BY n.prestador_cpfcnpj) AS grup
ON c.cnpj = grup.cnpjPrest;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu `JOIN` está na posição errada, ele deve vir antes do `SET` pois faz parte da especificação das tabelas:

```
UPDATE cadastro c
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(n.numero) AS qtd_notas, n.prestador_cpfcnpj AS cnpjPrest 
     FROM notas AS n 
     WHERE n.prestador_cpfcnpj 
     IN ( SELECT c.cnpj FROM cadastro AS c) 
     GROUP BY n.prestador_cpfcnpj) AS grup
ON c.cnpj = grup.cnpjPrest
SET c.ultimanota = (grup.qtd_notas + 1);
```

Comment: Ahh, muito obrigado! Deu certinho <3